# Need to add new picklist values to the existing custom picklist field using apex?

Tags: apex, metadata

Can anyone suggest me how to add new value to the existing custom picklist using apex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Running user needs to have Customize Application privilege so you really want this to be an admin type user.
2. Read the examples in the GIT package carefully - there is one for picklists. You need to read the CustomField from the MetaData API first then update, otherwise you'll smash all the existing picklist entries.

The relevant example in the package's MetadataServiceExamples.cls file is here:

```
public static void updatePicklist()
{
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();             

    // Read Custom Field
    MetadataService.CustomField customField = 
        (MetadataService.CustomField) service.readMetadata('CustomField', 
            new String[] { 'Lead.picklist__c' }).getRecords()[0];       

    // Add pick list values
    metadataservice.PicklistValue two = new metadataservice.PicklistValue();
    two.fullName= 'second';
    two.default_x=false;
    metadataservice.PicklistValue three = new metadataservice.PicklistValue();
    three.fullName= 'third';
    three.default_x=false;
    customField.picklist.picklistValues.add(two);
    customField.picklist.picklistValues.add(three);     

    // Update Custom Field
    handleSaveResults(
        service.updateMetadata(
            new MetadataService.Metadata[] { customField })[0]);        
}
```

Refered from this link : [here](https://andyinthecloud.com/2013/10/27/introduction-to-calling-the-metadata-api-from-apex/)

Comment: I know the package you're referring to, but others may not. Can you include an explicit link/description?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I'm getting error "variable doesn't exist: picklist". customField.picklist.picklistValues.add(two);
    customField.picklist.picklistValues.add(three);

Comment: done @DavidReed

Comment: please upvote & select as best answer if u find it useful @Rkumar

Comment: I'm getting error "variable doesn't exist: picklist". customField.picklist.picklistValues.add(two); customField.picklist.picklistValues.add(three);

Comment: did u create custom field like above? !@Rkumar

Comment: Mohit Kulkarni, I'm using Primary__c instead of picklist__c